# Street Fighter 4: what is meant by Technical and Reversal moves?

Tags: terminology, street-fighter-iv

What moves are considered Technical and Reversal in Street Fighter 4?

What do they mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two moves that are called "technical" by the engine: throw defense (LP+LK when your opponent tries to throw you) and quick stand (down when you are knocked down).

Reversals are related to timing. A reversal is a special move done at the first frame of recovery (after a knockdown, block stun or hit stun). In example, if you do a Shoryuken right after get up from a knockdown, it will count as a reversal.

Comment: many Thanks!so there are only 2 technical moves then. and only spl moves are considered for reversal.

Comment: Yeah. There are some moves that aren't valid for reversals, like fireballs, but I don't know the reasoning. There's a glossary in http://iplaywinner.com/glossary/ , it's pretty useful.